# Firmware update fails from SYSTEM session but works when ran from logged on session?

Tags: session, updates, firmware

I am using the Lenovo Firmware Update Tool:
https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/ca/fr/downloads/ds504448

The goal is to update the docking station's firmware.

The EXACT same script is ran (simply `ThinkPad_Hybrid_Dock_TVSU_FW.exe /all /silent`):

1-In SYSTEM session (via sccm or scheduled task) it ALWAYS fails with:

```
 Update fail.

 Failed to update the Device Firmware.
 Restart this program and try again.

 RC:60931
```

2-In a logged on user session, running the EXACT same script in the EXACT same way, it ALWAYS works:

```
 Update success.

 Success to update the Device Firmware.


 RC:0
```

Any idea if this is by design? What could prevent it from running in the SYSTEM account? This destroys the purpose of having a /silent switch. The goal is to deploy the firmware update via SCCM overnight when it's safe to do so. Having to log in and run the command defeats all automation possibilities. We have hundreds of docking stations to update...Right now, we would have to do it manually by logging in and running the script...This is a nightmare.

Also, if I test running the command within a logged on session, let's say userX, it works.

If I run the exact same script with the exact same userX credential but from a Scheduled Task or as a Windows Service, it doesn't work!

It seems there is something in the tool preventing it to run anywhere except from within a logged on session....?

After running PROCMON, something strange is happening. Ran successfully in a user session the log is 61 346 events. There are 14 entries of the software creating and querying it's result file:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnEfs.png

However, in the failed attempt running the same command as SYSTEM, there are a staggering 1 315 989 events (92% of the log) of the application seemingly trying to create that result txt file and failing (the CreateFile operation), i suspect ultimately it times out after trying, oh just over a million times.

Do you have any idea why it could be happening? The SYSTEM account has complete control on that folder's security rights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's by design the tool doesn't support silent install outside a logged session so the public don't brick their devices...Apparently we can contact our sales rep and get a commercial version of the tool which allows for silent updating.

See this administrator's response here :

https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-T400-T500-and-newer-T/Firmware-update-all-silent-always-FAILS-when-ran-from-SYSTEM/td-p/4503933**

So if you are in the same situation, you need to contact your lenovo rep and get the true "silent" version of the tool which is not available to the public.

Pasted answer in case link goes dead:

> Re: Firmware update (/all /silent) always FAILS when ran from SYSTEM
>   account but works if ran logged ‎08-19-2019 12:54 AM
>
> Hello & welcome to the Community,
>
> It is possible to deploy the dock firmware silently however due to the
>   high risk that a user disconnects the dock during the update, which
>   would result in the dock being rendered useless aka "bricked", the
>   silent install method is never released to the public domain. The
>   package is made available to commercial customers and you should be
>   able to request the ability through your sales representative; certain
>   agreements / parameters will need to be met beforehand.
>
> original:
>   https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Displays-Options-and-Accessories/Dock-Firmware-Deployment/m-p/4149494#M...
>
> Andy
>
> English Community Leader Please remember to come back and mark the
>   post that you feel solved your question as the solution, it earns the
>   member + points  Did you find a post helpfull? You can thank the
>   member by clicking on the star below their post awarding them Kudos
>
> Please don't ask me questions by Personal Message; questions belong in
>   the forums.